# How to edit specific text files with linux terminal

Tags: replace

I don't know how to edit some text files and make my job easier. How can I get specific lines inside a enourmous text file, grab it and send to another text file (a new document).

Example 1:

```
>text_xyz

ASDFGHJKLJGDSAQWEERTYYGFS

.>text_abc

ASDFWQRTYGEQ
```

So, I need to find those terms (>text_xyz) and grab the lines under the title (ASDFGHJKLJGDSAQWEERTYYGFS).

I think this isn't a difficult job, because when I find the starting code "**>**" I just need to stop "grabing" when I find another code starting with "**>**" .

Then, I'll get only those lines:

```
**>text_xyz**

**ASDFGHJKLJGDSAQWEERTYYGFS**
```

How can I do this using Linux terminal?

Comment: i `grep` is the way to go also putting the grep in a shell script would make it portable and a lot easier.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing a sequence from a fasta file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26144692/printing-a-sequence-from-a-fasta-file)

Answer (score 0):

`grep -A 1 foo text_xyz > new.txt`

Comment: But how do I set my text file as a "PATH" to the grep command?

Comment: how do you tell it to look in the text file to grep or output? for information on the command run `man grep`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's more easier now, hahaha.